# Apple Configurator 2 - How to edit a profile

Tags: ios

I am using Apple Configurator 2 to program some iPads. I am able to create a profile but editing that profile once it is made has completely eluded me.

Am I missing something here> How do I edit a profile once it's been setup?

Comment: OMG I have just found it :O

If anyone has completely overlooked this option you need to go to File > Open! Then select your profile.

Comment: Rather than answering in the comments, feel free to write a proper answer and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

> You need to go to `File > Open`, then select your profile.

<sub><sup>(Posting Alex's comment as an answer, as he seems to be inactive since Dec 4, 2015, and I nearly missed the solution as I tend to skip reading the comments.)</sup></sub>